# Using default wordcount javascript in Wordpress on custom wp_editor() areas

Tags: wp-editor

I have two `wp_editor()` instances on pages and posts used to populate the sidebars of my three-column website. I would like to use the default wordpress word-count script on the two wp-editor areas to get the word-count of the content within them.

I enqueued the script and added the required HTML but the wordcount was always that of the main content editor area.

Has anyone managed to use this functionality with custom wp_editor areas and what HTML will I use?

I have searched on the web but could not find any examples where the default script is used.

Thanks in advance
nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git this to work by using the following line of code in my theme's functions.php.

```
$wordcount = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ), 0 );
```

I got this piece of code from a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485673/counting-words-on-a-html-web-page-using-php).

The only disadvantage with this code is that it does not update dynamically which is not a big issue as the current wordcount will show up every time the post is updated.

The problem with using javascript on which event I should trigger the wordpress function on.

WordPress's wordcount functionality is tightly coupled with the default editor and I had to duplicate their javascript to try and get similar functionality which is not a good choice.

I would still like to get some thoughts on this by a more experienced WP developer.

Thank you.
nav